# what is the best way to move a directory in a wan?

Tags: delphi

I'm using the last delphi 10.4.1 and I was wondering what is the best way to move a directory in a wan?

I was thinking about using this:

```
ZeroMemory(@fos, SizeOf(fos));

    with fos do
    begin
      wFunc  := FO_MOVE;
      fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY + FOF_NOCONFIRMATION + FOF_SILENT;
      pFrom  := PChar(CartellaDa + #0);
      pTo    := PChar(CartellaA)
    end;

    vRet := ShFileOperation(fos);
```

but I'm not sure if it works fine in a WAN where connection could drop.
I also read MS advice the use of IFileOperation which I'm not sure how to use it.
There is also the FTP option..

I need to be able to move the files and the folders, create everything if is missing and overwrite files if folders already exists

thank you!

Comment: As long as Windows networking is working across the WAN, shell operations as well as all Windows API (Including the one embedded in Delphi RTL) will work. To better answer your question, we need to know which kind of WAN you are talking about! Does Windows Explorer works with this WAN?

Comment: You should be able to use TDirectory and TFile in System.IOUtils. You can verifiy the content by a final checksum

Comment: It's a WAN with an MPLS so it's similar to a LAN. Yes explorer works. I just would like to know which one is the best way to do it.

Comment: tdirectory does not work because destination must not exists